# Porque al usar serialize se muestra así {i:0;s:2:"37";i:1;s:2:"36";}] en mi index.php?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Buenas actualmente me encuentro realizando un proyecto y necesito crear un sistema de categorías/tags por publicación. Conseguí que funcionase usando el método de Serialize pero me gustaría que se mostraran las categorías seleccionadas en las publicaciones de mi blog, porque al ingresar `<p class="cap-title"><?php echo $post['topic_id']?></p>` me aparece lo siguiente en la web: a:2:{i:0;s:2:"37";i:1;s:2:"36";}

Me dijeron que use Unserialize pero no entiendo muy bien donde agregarlo.

¿Usar este método para crear las categorías es confiable?
Ayuda por favor!.

código: topics.php

```
if (isset($_POST['add-post'])) {
    $_POST['topic_id']=serialize($_POST['topic_id']);
    $errors = validatePost($_POST);
    
    if (!empty($_FILES['image']['name'])) {
        $image_name = time() . '_' . $_FILES['image']['name'];
        $destination = "../../images/" . $image_name;
        
        $result = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $destination);
        
        if ($result){
            $_POST['image'] = $image_name;
        } else {
            array_push($errors, "¡Algo fallo al subir la imagen!");
        }
        
        
    } else {
      array_push($errors, "¡Necesitas subir una imagen!");
    }
    
    if (count($errors) === 0){
        unset($_POST['add-post']);
        $post_id = create($table, $_POST);
        $_SESSION['message'] = '¡Post creado correctamente!';
        $_SESSION['type'] = 'success';
        header('location: ../../admin/posts/index.php');
        exit();
    } else {
        $title = $_POST['title'];
        $body = $_POST['body'];
        $topic = $_POST['topic_id']; // array('test','test2')
    }
}

if (isset($_GET['id'])){
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $post = selectOne($table, ['id' => $id]);
    $id = $post['id'];
    $title = $post['title'];
    $body = $post['body'];
    $topic = $post['topic_id'];
}

if (isset($_GET['del_id'])){
    $id = $_GET['del_id'];    
    $count = delete($table, $id);
    $_SESSION['message'] = '¡Post eliminado correctamente!';
    $_SESSION['type'] = 'success';
    header('location: ../../admin/posts/index.php');
    exit();
}

if (isset($_POST['update-post'])){
    $_POST['topic_id']=serialize(array_values($_POST['topic_id']));
    $errors = validateEdit($_POST); 
    
    if (count($errors) === 0){
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        unset($_POST['update-post'], $_POST['id']);
        $post_id = update($table, $id, $_POST);
        $_SESSION['message'] = '¡Post actualizado correctamente!';
        $_SESSION['type'] = 'success';
        header('location: ../../admin/topics/index.php');
        exit();        
    } else {
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $title = $_POST['title'];
        $body = $_POST['body'];
        $topic = $_POST['topic_id'];
}
} 
?>
```

imágenes:

[image: imagen]
[image: index]

Comment: Intenta con `<p class="cap-title"><?php echo unserialize($post['topic_id'])?></p>`

Comment: @alanfcm Hola, gracias por responder pero lo intente y me sale este error: Notice: Array to string conversion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ¿Por qué al usar *serialize* se muestra así {i:0;s:2:“37”;i:1;s:2:“36”;}]?

La respuesta a esa pregunta específica es:

```
a:2:{i:0;s:2:"37";i:1;s:2:"36";}
```

- **a:2** quiere decir que se trata de un arreglo con dos elementos
- **i:0;s:2:"37"** Quiere decir que el primer elemento tiene índice entero (i) con valor cero y el contenido es una cadena (s) de 2 caracteres de longitud y valor "37"
- **i:1;s:2:"36"** Quiere decir que el segundo elemento tiene índice entero (i) con valor 1 y el contenido es una cadena (s) de 2 caracteres de longitud y valor "36"

En resumen, cuando aplicas `unserialize()` obtienes un arreglo:

```
["37", "36"]
```

Para mostrar las categorías, lo ideal sería que tengas un arreglo asociativo `id_categoria => 'nombre_categoria'` y solo recorres:

```
<?php
$topics = [
    36 => 'Test1',
    37 => 'Test2',
];

?>
<p class="cap-title">
<?php
// Obtener arreglo de categorías
$categorias = unserialize($_POST['topic_id']);
// Recorrer arreglo para mostrar cada una
foreach($categorias as $cat) {
   echo $topics[$cat];
}
?>
</p>
```

> ¿Usar este método para crear las categorías es confiable?

La respuesta a esto es meramente basada en opiniones y aquí va la mía: Es tan confiable como puedas y sepas manejarlo, por ejemplo: debes considerar cómo mantener consistencia en el catálogo de categorías, si se elimina una, tienes que verificar que no esté siendo usada en alguna publicación.

Habrá quienes te digan que debes crear una tabla aparte para establecer las relaciones y, probablemente, sea lo más adecuado para programar siempre basado en buenas prácticas.

Comment: Gracias me ayudaste muchísimo!, usando este método ha sido el mas fácil para mi porque recién estoy comenzando en este mundo de php y sql, y no se como crear una tabla aparte para establecer las relaciones. Por eso pregunte si este método es confiable y no me traería complicaciones en el futuro.